# virtually VS largely

Tags: difference

- `largely`, From google's Dictionary:

  > to a great extent; on the whole; mostly.

`largely` seems quite like `virtually` and `almost`.

Here diffs virtually and almost: [difference between virtually and almost](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48053/difference-between-virtually-and-almost)

What about `largely`? When should prefer `largely` over `almost` and `virtually`j

Comment: You *could* think of largely as a big piece of a pie, while (virtually) and almost as the whole pie minus (very) small pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'largely' means 'mostly'.

'mostly' could be anything from 50.01% to 99.99%.

'virtually' means slightly less than 100%. Everything but a small percentage.

So, 'virtually' generally means more than 'largely'.

Comment: +1. Or **virtually** can mean slightly more than 0% in context.  *There was **virtually nothing** left of the pie.*  It can be paraphrased, "for all intents and purposes" or as *we might as well say* there was nothing left of the pie, so little of it remained.

Comment: yeah, negative of almost everything is almost nothing.